# how to select kendo-drop down in selenium webdriver using python or java

Tags: java, python, selenium-webdriver, kendo-dropdown

in kendo dropdown, I get only class name can't get other elements from inspect element so what should I do 
I get only this fields by inspecting element

Shardul Patel

Comment: Where is the code you've tried? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Use keyboard keys in selenium to move up and down to select the kendo drop down values.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendkeys(keys.DOWN).build().perform();
```

Use with your webelement and get the desired results. Do let me know in case of any concerns.